# Move multiple array columns PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, split

I'm writing a small script which will split one column into three from .csv file. The csv file has an array with 18 columns, I need to split 5th one and insert the data into [6][7][8], how can I move everything whats [6]-[18] to [9]-[21] so my data won't be overwritten?

Comment: Hello Welcome to StackOverflow. Here's a quick note that you should read on asking questions. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Using a zero length third parameter, you can "inject" another array into an existing array...

```
// Make a 18 length array for testing
$array = array_fill( 0, 18, 'old' );
// Make a 3 length array for testing
$add = array_fill( 0, 3, 'new' );
// splice the $add array into $array at the 6th index
array_splice( $array, 6, 0, $add );
// done!
print_r( $array );
```

Comment: I was a bit confused by the numbers and indexes in your question, but the 'old' and 'new' strings should be clear as to how its behaving, really you just need to mess with the `6` here to get the right offset :)

Comment: it's working as a charm, all I had to do is array_splice($column,5,1,$matches); where $column is entire data from array and $matches are the previously split values :)

Comment: Ah ok, is the 5th column is CSV data? great, that `1` length parameter is perfect then :)

Comment: yes, it is! :) i had to check why it doesn't paste with 0 correctly, had no idea why, just wrote 1 and its great

Comment: so in your sample of `($column,5,1,$matches)`, the code means "_from at 5th index, remove 1 array item, then insert this other array from the 5th_"